# imagemagick scripts on managed host

Tags: imagemagick, hosting

I am new to imagemagick and wanted to use some of [fred scripts](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php) on my managed Sever (Hetzner - linux server). Imagemagick is installed and core features like `convert` works but how do I call the script? When I try to run something I don't receive any errors and results. As example for the "3Drotate" script I am using this php code

```
exec("3Drotate pan=45 auto=zc input.jpg 3d_output.jpg", $array, $return);
```

The script I downloaded lies in the same directory where I call this function (so not in the /bin where imagemagick is installed but in some www/public dir).
I tried to use an absolute path and setting the temp dir in the imagemagick script - both approaches didn't help.

Comment: Try CHMOD to 777 on the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you follow the instructions on my [home page](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick) for installing the scripts? See the Pointers for Use sections.

After doing so, try:

```
<?php
exec("bash 3Drotate pan=45 auto=zc input.jpg 3d_output.jpg 2>&1", $out,$returnval);
foreach($out as $text)
{echo "$text<br>";}
?>
```

Do you get any error messages?

Please note my scripts need to be licensed, if used for commercial purposes. My contact information is in the scripts and on my home page. You may contact me offline for more help, if the above does not work.

Comment: thx your answer helped me solving it (I had to use absolute paths additionally to your changes)